# Need to Remove the selected Access Rights

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to fetch the Mailboxpermission by excluding some Access Rights from the Result.

I have Tried by excluding the Access rights using the below command.

PS C:\Users\XXXX> get-mailboxpermission -Identity 'CCCC.XXXX.com/Users/test_50' |select AccessRights | where { _.AccessRights -ne "FullAccess"}

This is the actual Result i am getting:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> get-mailboxpermission -Identity 'CCCC.XXXX.com/Users/test_50' |select AccessRights

AccessRights
------------
{FullAccess, ReadPermission}
{FullAccess}
{FullAccess}
{FullAccess}
{FullAccess}
{FullAccess}
{ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
```

I would tried Excluding "FullAccess" in the below Command:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> get-mailboxpermission -Identity 'CCCC.XXXX.com/Users/test_50' |select AccessRights | where { $_.AccessRights -ne "FullAcce
ss"}

AccessRights
------------
{FullAccess, ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, ReadPermission}
{FullAccess, DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
```

Expected Output:

```
AccessRights
------------
{ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{ReadPermission}
{DeleteItem, ReadPermission, ChangePermission, ChangeOwner}
{ReadPermission}
```

Comment: try `-notcontains` instead of `-ne`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just trying to filter your output, a combination of `-replace` operator and `.where()` method will suffice.

```
(get-mailboxpermission -Identity 'CCCC.XXXX.com/Users/test_50' |
Select-Object @{n="AccessRights";e={$_.AccessRights -replace "FullAccess(?:, )?"}}).where{$_.AccessRights -ne ""}
```

The `-replace` operator here will replace the string `FullAccess,` or `FullAccess` with an empty string. The `.where()` method removes the lines that just contain an empty string. Since the replace uses a Regex, `(?:, )?` is evaluated as a non capture group (`?:()`) matching on comma followed by space zero or one time (`?`).

The `Select-Object` command is using a hashtable to preserve the `AccessRights` header name while manipulating the pipeline object.

Comment: Thanks Its work fine !!. Can you help me on removing `ReadPermission` as well. Now I would like to Remove Multiple AccessRights `FullAccess` and `ReadPermission`.

Comment: `"FullAccess(?:, )?"` would need to change to `"(FullAccess|ReadPermission)(?:,
 )?"`.